# cannot find the datastore during the compiling in Angular2

Tags: wakanda

When I try to run my page in Wakanda studio 1.1.3, I am getting an error during the compiling when converting the TS to JS. It shows me an error stating "cannot find the datastore"; which is present in my wakanda database. Is anyone else getting the same error?

here is the code:

```
this.wakanda.catalog.then(ds=>{
    ds.TestDatabase.testmethod().then(op=>{
        console.log(op);
    });
});
```

my wakanda.service.ts is of the following

```
import {WakandaClient} from 'wakanda-client/browser/no-promise';

export class Wakanda {

  private _client: WakandaClient;
  private _catalog;

  constructor() {
    //this._client = new WakandaClient({ host: 'http://127.0.0.1:8081' });
    this._client = new WakandaClient({});
    this._catalog = null;
  }

  get catalog() {
    if (!this._catalog) {
      return this._client.getCatalog().then(c => {
        this._catalog = c;

        return c;
      });
    }

    return Promise.resolve(this._catalog);
  }

  get directory() {
    return this._client.directory;
  }

  get wakandaClientVersion() {
    return this._client.version();
  }
}
```

where TestDatavase is a table in my datastore and has a method called `testmethod`.

> [default]
>   /Users/adithyavinayak/Documents/Wakanda/solutions/TestDatabase/TestDatabase/web/src/app/home/home.component.ts:21:8
>   Property 'TestDatabase' does not exist on type 'Catalog'. [default]
>   Checking finished with 4 errors

[image]

This one happens even if i make a call to any datastore during compile time.

Comment: Can you post a bit of your code, please?

Comment: i have updated the question for further reference

Comment: finally can you show us also the full error, please?

Comment: The error code which i am getting is TS:2339 propery'SvrMethod' doesn't exist of type catalog

Comment: i have added my wakanda.service.ts too for your further reference

Comment: have you create at least 1 entity in the TestDatabase table?

Comment: yes i do have some entity inside the table

Comment: your code seems correct. I have no clue, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem is by using the return type of the catalog to any

```
this.wakanda.catalog.then((ds:any)=>{
    ds.TestDatabase.testmethod().then(op=>{
        console.log(op);
    });
});
```

This one works without any problem during the time of compilation.